# How can I extend a built in component in Angular?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use an Angular component and would like to use a custom template.

https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-text-input-autocomplete/docs/directives/TextInputAutocompleteDirective.html

According to this documentation, `menuComponent` can extended by a built in `TextInputAutocompleteMenuComponent` component to use a custom template.

So, how can I replace that component template to use my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the custom template. Is it drop down or text box because 'TextInputAutocompleteMenuComponent' is specifically written for dropdown.

Below are my opinions which may be helpful for you: 
You can make use of 'TextInputAutocompleteContainerComponent' along with 'TextInputAutocompleteDirective' for you custom template which works on text-area/text-box.

If you really want 'TextInputAutocompleteMenuComponent' with custom template then you can create new component which extends this component and bind all events with parent class funtions in your template.